# Spark: how to iterate over spark arrayType as an expression

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Building a recursive function.

```
def loop(path: String, dt: DataType, acc:Seq[String]): Seq[String] = {
  dt match {
  case s: ArrayType => 
       s.fields.flatMap(f => loop(path + "." + f.name, f.dataType, acc))
  case s: StructType =>      
    s.fields.flatMap(f => loop(path + "." + f.name, f.dataType, acc))
  case other => 
    acc:+ path
}
```

I have an error saying that "error: value fields is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.types.ArrayType". So how do I iterate over each element of the arrayType and return a flattened sequence of strings?

Comment: You don't. Individual values are not reflected in schema.

Comment: Except it does. My schema appears to include the elements, which are of structType. I would like the loop to parse them and return a flattened sequence of string as well.

Comment: It doesn't. The only thing that is reflected in schema of `ArrayType` is the type of elements. Do you want to access type of array? If so use `f.dataType`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the trick is using .elementType

```
def loop(path: String, dt: DataType, acc:Seq[String]): Seq[String] = {
  dt match {
  case s: ArrayType =>
       loop(path, s.elementType, acc)
  case s: StructType =>      
    s.fields.flatMap(f => loop(path + "." + f.name, f.dataType, acc))
  case other => 
    acc:+ path
}
```